# How to call the same current route with different route values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Following is the exact scenario in my MVC 4 application.

There is a common view which gets launched through two different controller actions. I have set up both the routes in `RouteConfig.cs`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "LByYearMonth",
    "L/{year}/{month}",
    new { controller = "Library", action = "DisplayByYearMonth" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "LByPresetYearMonth",
    "L/{Preset}/{year}/{month}",
    new { controller = "Library", action = "DisplayByPresetYearMonth" }
);
```

Both the above actions launch `LibraryBooks.cshtml` view.

Now on this view, I have a monthpicker, and a Button controls (labelled as "GO").

Clicking on "GO" button should call the invoking route by supplying the parameters in "year" and "month", respectively.

That means, if a view is loaded through `LByYearMonth` route, the button should lead user to the corresponding action by supplying selected year and month.
And if the view is loaded through `LByPresetYearMonth` route, the button should lead user to its corresponding action by supplying preset, selected year and month.

Any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: What are the possible values of Preset? or is it a static string?

Comment: Preset is also passed by the user in the URL. Consider it as "Author" in library application

Comment: i am still not sure about this question. Please see this jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/3tRze/1/ if that is what you are asking for.